# How to check if the main Draw call has been missed for the previous frame?

Tags: c#, xna

I'd like to be able to see if main `Draw` call wasn't made the last frame. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay, there is this main Draw call in XNA. Sometimes a frame is dropped, so it is not called. I'd like to be able to programmatically get a boolean, true if it was dropped.

Comment: Do you mean that you didn't call Draw, or the Draw function was called, but the frame you rendered at that moment was not updated to the monitor? Basically, what do you mean by dropped?

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus You probably don't know, but XNA calls `Update` and `Draw` methods automatically, and the `Draw` isn't necessarily called after `Update`. I see you don't answer a lot on XNA related questions, I'd recommend to look up a few things.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus The question is completely clear and unambiguous if you know XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can have a couple of variables:

```
int lastupdate
int lastdraw
```

after your update loop

```
lastupdate++;
```

after your draw loop

```
lastdraw = lastupdate.
```

That way, you can use the difference between `lastdraw` and `lastupdate` to determine how many update calls have occured since your last draw call.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve here. But there is a property in GameTime that might help.

It's called GameTime.IsRunningSlowly:

> Gets a value indicating that the game loop is taking longer than its
>   TargetElapsedTime. In this case, the game loop can be considered to be
>   running too slowly and should do something to "catch up."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.isrunningslowly(v=xnagamestudio.30).aspx

Comment: I need to be 100% sure that the previous frame was dropped, and I don't know if this property is 100%.